# Как нажать на кнопку с помощью консоли сайта JS

Tags: javascript, button, site

Нужно нажать на эту кнопку, не знаю как

```
<button id="continue_button" class="stats-btn__continue">Продолжить</button>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно вот так:

```
document.getElementById("continue_button").click();
```